# With draggable, how can I get the distance the element traveled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extract the distance that an element has traveled since I picked it up. I tried grabbing the `offset` and `position` of the `target` of the events passed to the `stop` handler, but they always come up as zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the direction traveled in the `drag` callback like so:

```
var diffX = 0;
var diffY = 0;

$('#some_div').draggable({
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        var start = ui.originalPosition,
            end = ui.position;

        diffX = end.left - start.left;
        diffY = end.top - start.top;
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        console.info('Dragged: X = %o, Y = %o', diffX, diffY);
    }
});
```